# r gsub - replace only first match of a word

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string like this: "21st-August-2017" and I would like to replace the "st" after 21 with "xx" so that the result is

"25xx-August-2017"

I have tried using regex repetition quantifiers, e.g.

```
gsub("st{1}", "xx", "21st-August-2017")
```

But this still replaces both instances of "st". How can I specify that it should match only the first instance of "st"?

Comment: `sub("st", "xx", "21st-August-2017", fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 14):

Please use `sub` instead of `gsub`.

> Replace the first occurrence of a pattern with `sub` or replace all occurrences with `gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sub`. The two *sub functions differ only in that sub replaces only the first occurrence of a pattern whereas gsub replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookbehind

```
s <- c("21st-August-2017")
gsub("(?<=\\d)st", "xx", s, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "21xx-August-2017"
```

Lookarounds ascertain a specific position, in your case that a digit comes before `st`.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EazskA/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify a more specific regex. For your case

`gsub("(\\d1{1,2}st){1}", "xx", "21st-August-2017")`

would work (replace all occurrences of `"st"` preceded by one or two numbers)

If you need to do a lot of string manipulation also look into the **stringr** package which has more verbose function names and a imho more sensible ordering of function paramters:

`stringi::stri_replace_first_regex("21st-August-2017", "st{1}", "xx")`
`stringi::stri_replace_first_fixed("21st-August-2017", "st", "xx")`